# Getting job listings into InDeed from my wordpress site

Tags: xml, wordpress, feed

I have a client that would like their job postings to automatically show up on indeed.  I was looking for information on the best way to proceed.  The client's site is built with WordPress.

One possibility is to have them create the jobs directly in indeed.  Then I can show the jobs on their web-site with an indeed feed reader.  I have not had success finding an indeed reader that can restrict by employer.

Another possibility is to have an automated export of data to indeed.  I have not found a plug-in that can do this.

Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You can import it by simply using this class and create an object to it,

```
class Indeed{
const DEFAULT_FORMAT = "json";
const API_SEARCH_ENDPOINT = "http://api.indeed.com/ads/apisearch";
const API_JOBS_ENDPOINT = "http://api.indeed.com/ads/apigetjobs";
private static $API_SEARCH_REQUIRED = array("userip", "useragent", array("q", "l"));
private static $API_JOBS_REQUIRED = array("jobkeys");
public function __construct($publisher, $version = "2"){
    $this->publisher = $publisher;
    $this->version = $version;
}
public function search($args){
    return $this->process_request(self::API_SEARCH_ENDPOINT, $this->validate_args(self::$API_SEARCH_REQUIRED, $args));
}
public function jobs($args){
    $valid_args = $this->validate_args(self::$API_JOBS_REQUIRED, $args);
    $valid_args["jobkeys"] = implode(",", $valid_args['jobkeys']);
    return $this->process_request(self::API_JOBS_ENDPOINT, $valid_args);
}
private function process_request($endpoint, $args){
    $format = (array_key_exists("format", $args) ? $args["format"] : self::DEFAULT_FORMAT);
    $raw = ($format == "xml" ? true : (array_key_exists("raw", $args) ? $args["raw"] : false));
    $args["publisher"] = $this->publisher;
    $args["v"] = $this->version;
    $args["format"] = $format;
    $c = curl_init(sprintf("%s?%s", $endpoint, http_build_query($args)));
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $result = curl_exec($c);
    curl_close($c);
    $r = (!$raw ? json_decode($result, $assoc = true) : $result);
    return $r;
}
private function validate_args($required_fields, $args){
    foreach($required_fields as $field){
        if(is_array($field)){
            $has_one_required = false;
            foreach($field as $f){
                if(array_key_exists($f, $args)){
                    $has_one_required = True;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(!$has_one_required){
                throw new Exception(sprintf("You must provide one of the following %s", implode(",", $field)));
            }
        } elseif(!array_key_exists($field, $args)){
            throw new Exception("The field $field is required");
        }
    }
    return $args;
}
}
```

and you can create object like this.

```
$client = new Indeed("YOUR_PUBLISHER_NUMBER");

$params = array(
  "jobkeys" => array("5898e9d8f5c0593f", "c2c41f024581eae5"),
);

$results = $client->jobs($params);
```

and you can get few plugins from WordPress itself . 
[indeed importer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/indeed-job-importer/)

Comment: I have a publisher account but I don't see  how this only get the jobs from my company?